Python equivalent of source() R function
I am an R user trying to learn python.
I used to use the source() function in R to execute a script inside another script and I would like to do the same in python. Thank you in advance for your help.
Please see an example below.
script "common step.R" : the script I want to execute in the script "analysis1.R"
file_ID_2 = file_ID %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(n_val = n())

data_2 = data %>%
  left_join(file_ID_2, by=c("ID")) %>%
  mutate(n_val = ifelse(!is.na(n_val), n_val, 0)) %>%
  mutate(cdk=ifelse(n_val>0, "Yes", "No")) %>%
  distinct(ID, .keep_all = T) %>%
  filter(!is.na(.data[[variable]])) %>%
  rename(variable := !!variable)

script 'analysis1" : script where I load my files/packages and were I perform my first analysis using the script 'common step.R" that will do common steps for several analysis using the same raw data
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

# data
#####################

file_ID = data.frame(ID=c("I1", "I1", "I2", "I3", "I6", "I9" ),
                     cl1=c(7,4,5,8,7, 1))
  
data = data.frame(ID=c("I1", "I2", "I3", "I4", "I5", "I6", "I7", "I8", "I9" ),
                  Sex = c("F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F"),
                  groupe = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
                  var1=c(8,9,6,6,NA,5,6,2, 5),
                  var2=c(7,12,5,9,9,11,8,2, 7),
                  var3=c(NA,4,7,9,5,10,6,NA, 4))

# variable that i want to analyse
####################################

variable="var1"

# Execution of the script "common step.R" that will use the data loaded in this script
#########################################################################################

source("./common step.R")

# Analysis using the output of the script previously executed
#########################################################################################

data_3 = data_2 %>%
  group_by(Sex, groupe) %>%
  mutate(mean_value = mean(variable))
......


Script "common_step.py"
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def First_step(tab_1, tab_2, vari): 
    tab_1["nb_val"] = tab_1.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform('count')
    tab_3 = pd.merge(tab_2, tab_1, how="left", on="ID")
    tab_3["nb_val"] = tab_3["nb_val"].replace(np.nan, 0)
    tab_3['cdk'] = ['Yes' if count > 0 else 'No' for count in tab_3['nb_val']]
    tab_3 = tab_3.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'])
    tab_3 = tab_3.rename(columns = {vari : 'variable'})
    tab_3=tab_3[ ~ tab_3['variable'].isna()]
 
    return tab_3

script 'analysis1" in python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data
#####################
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": ["I1", "I2", "I3", "I4", "I5", "I6", "I7", "I8", "I9"],
        "Sex" : ["F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F"],
        "groupe" : ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"],
         "var1" : [8,9,6,6,np.nan,5,6,2, 5],
         "var2" : [7,12,5,9,9,11,8,2, 7],
         "var3" : [np.nan,4,7,9,5,10,6,np.nan, 4]
    }
)


file_ID =  pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID" : ["I1", "I1", "I2", "I3", "I6", "I9" ],
        "cl1" : [7,4,5,8,7, 1]
            }
)


# variable that i want to analyse
####################################

variable_to_analyse="var1"

# Execution of the script "common_step.py" that will use the data loaded in this script
#########################################################################################


import common_steps

tab_3 = common_steps.First_step(file_ID, data, variable_to_analyse)


# Analysis using the output of the script previously executed
#########################################################################################

tab_3["mean_value"] = tab_3.groupby(['Sex', 'groupe'])['variable'].transform('mean')
data_3 = tab_3
......



i think it does!

Actually not, I have tried several methods of this post, but they are not working

For what it’s worth source() is a very poor substitute for Python modules (which use import). A much better solution in R is provided by the package ‘box’.

If you have __name__=='__main__'-unconditionned module-level imperative commands in script A.py, you can simply do import A from script B.py.

import is indeed the python equivalent of source, or at least as close as you're going to get without doing something stupidly dangerous. However, python programs are often written in such a way that import might not do what you expect it to when coming from R's source.
Notably, the files (modules) that you import cannot directly access the namespace of the importing file. You can achieve that effect if you really wanted to, but I would recommend strongly against it. What this means is that the file you import cannot use the variables defined in your parent script unless you give them to it explicitly.
Let's start with a simple example. Here, a,b,c are three typical constructs of python modules. Most python files are some combination of these.
a.py
   print("Printing from a.py")

In this example, anytime a.py is imported, the code is executed. Note that this is often fine for small scripts and projects, but is generally discouraged when your code base is more complex. Note that in this structure, all of the code in a.py is executed as soon as you import it, leaving you no opportunity to inject external data from the parent file (there may be a contrived way to do it, but please don't try if you have to ask how).
In better python programs and larger code bases than a single file, you'll see structures like what follow. The rule of thumb to keep in mind here is that importing a python file should not have any side effects, i.e., your code should not execute just because the file was imported, but execution must require some other explicit trigger - typically a function call.
b.py
  def main(some_args=None):
     print("Printing from b.py")

  if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()

b.py is the traditional way in which python scripts are recommended to be written. When you import b, the code block protected by the if __name__.. guard is not executed. However, when you run python b.py, __name__ will be __main__, and the code in that block gets executed. This allows the file to be used as a script as well as imported as a 'library' by other programs. When properly written, such files will not have any bare python statements (like the bare print statement a.py had) outside of the if __name__... block. It will only have functions, classes, other imports, and maybe a few globals.
c.py
  def some_function(some_args): 
    print("Printing from c.py")

c.py is the kind of file written to be used as a library or separate module. When you import this, absolutely nothing happens other than importing c.py into your files namespace.
Here's how you use these modules, and where applicable, provide your data to these modules :
your_program.py
  import a
  import b
  import c

  your_data={'something': 'interesting'}
  
  b.main(some_args=your_data)
  c.some_function(some_args=your_data)


If you really do want to deal in globals, which is not something I would recommend for your kind of use case, remember that globals are global only at the module level. So, for example, you can do, from your_program.py :
   ...
   b.some_variable_name = your_data
   c.some_variable_name = your_data
   ...

The functions in b and c can access some_variable_name after you've done this if you've also explicitly declared some_variable_name as a global within the scope of the function, like so :
modified c.py
  some_vaiable_name = None

  def some_function(some_args): 
    global some_variable_name
    print("Printing from c.py")

Similarly, variables defined in the imported module don't show up in the namespace of the file doing the importing. Assuming they are globals in the imported module, you'd need to access it through the namespace of the imported module. (For example c.some_variable_name in the example). The preferred way to get responses back from module functions is as function return values (For example, some_result = c.some_function(your_data) in the example).

Thank you for this precise response. I think I better understood how to proceed but when I want to use import (after defining c script) I got this error : No module naled c. I am using jupyter notebook. So my script are saved as .ipynb. Does it the problem for import error ?

I do not know how .ipynbs work, though I would guess you should name the modules you are importing .py instead, with only a top level .ipynb essentially providing a user interface. You would also put your python module files in a place in which the ipynb can find it. Again, I'm not entirely certain what paths are involved with ipynbs, but a good place to start would be to make sure the .py files are right next to the ipynb file, and not inside any subfolders.

Thank you. I suspected the .ipnb was the problem. Renaming in .py did not solve the problem but using a simple text edit to write the "c" script did. I applied your method on my example and coud do what I was expected. I did not had to deal with global. Can you take a look on my edit and tell me if I did not do something not recommandated and if the way I proceed looks fine (or at least better that I intented to do) ? Thank you again

@Av65 your current code looks fine. There are some style improvements you could make over time if you're going to be writing more python. imports are typically done at the top of the file in python world, for example. You can search for and take a look at PEP8, which specifies the commonly accepted way to format python code. When you work with other people or if your code travels, it helps to stay 'pythonic'. Otherwise, I don't see any obvious errors. Functionally, as long as it works, it works.
